# Windows 10 night light color not returned when mode turned off

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

I have a dual monitor setup I just upgraded to identical Samsung monitors and a single AMD Radeon RX580 graphics card. I also have two computers hooked up to both.

After installation I had one monitor input from a laptop and the second monitor input from a desktop. Everything was great. It was late and on the desktop I wanted to try night light. I set it adjusted and adjusted the color tint. Everything was great but decided I did not like it. I shut off night light but the display never returned to the default brightness setting the other monitor still has.

Before trying sleep mode the monitors did have the same color warmth.

Both monitors are connected to the card using same brand display port cables. Prior to trying the night light the color warmth appeared the same.

When both monitors are using the desktop input in extend display mode there is a distinct tint difference between them. The monitors are side by side with the only gap between them the edge bezel. I am using the mostly white Windows settings application window to compare. When I position it to cross both monitors the monitor I tried night light on is definitely warmer with a less blue in it.

Both the computer and monitors have been powered off and no change.

What I have checked/attempted so far without resolution:

- Reset both monitors to default settings even though I never changed their settings. I have compared all the internal monitor settings for color tint/hue/etc. and they are the same.
- Using the AMD Radeon settings software I have reset both displays color management to default even though they were the same.
- In Windows display settings confirmed the night light setting is off for both displays. Just in case there is some bug still using the night light warmth setting both displays are set all the way to the right.
- In Windows display setting compared every setting I can see between the display and they are both exactly the same.

I  have looked for some higher level display or graphics setting or properties settings that could explain it but I can't find anything.

Help? I am a fairly experienced PC user but I have reached the end of what I know to check.

If it would help to see a picture of the warmth difference I can provide one.

Comment: I’m not sure how “sleep mode” and “color” go together at all. In “sleep” mode the monitor is OFF. But that is beside the point. You’ve provided enough information to recognize that both monitors have manufacturing differences. Unfortunately this happens. Either try to adjust the monitor’s color values to more closely match the other monitor or send them both back. Sometimes it’s a crapshoot with certain manufacturers. Or it’s possible one of the monitors is actually defective. The exact same brand and model CAN look different.

Comment: My apologies for mixing up statements. I corrected the problem above. What I meant by sleep mode is really the Windows night light setting.